# Using Pandas To Grab Row Data From Various Columns Using An Indexed Row

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am looking for a little nudge on where to look for the answer of this. I have finally gotten my code to where it will return the row index of a user search. Now my problem is I have the row index, I now need to be able to take that row # returned from the user search and start spitting out each column data from that row, how can I print the indexed row (Searched_Service_Row_Location) from each column? May be simple but I have spent a good amount of this Sunday looking for how to do so, any tips is much appreciated. Tried to go down the .iloc road but couldn't get what I wanted.

```
from tkinter import *

import pandas as pd


database = pd.ExcelFile('C:/Code/CODETEST.xlsx').parse(sheet_name="Sheet1", skiprows=0, nrows=3)

excel_data_df = pd.read_excel('CODETEST.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1',)


WHAT = excel_data_df._values

print (WHAT)

print (excel_data_df)


##Creating a service list for all services listed under "Serivce name" Column
My_Service_List = (excel_data_df['ServiceName'].tolist())


My_Multicast_List = (excel_data_df['SRC DRAWING'].tolist())

column2 = excel_data_df.iloc[0, 3]
column3 = excel_data_df.iloc[:0, 4]


root = Tk()

##Creating Entries
Group = Entry(root, width=50)
Group.grid(row=0, column=5)
Source = Entry(root, width=50)
Source.grid(row=1, column=5)
Service = Entry(root, width=50)
Service.grid(row=2, column=5)

##Creating a global var to store row # of service searched
global Searched_Service_Row_Location

##Creating Signal Flow Box
def Standard_flow():
    global Source1
    global My_Service_List
    global Test
    global column2
    Standard_window = Tk()
    ##Source1_Text = tk.StringVar()
    ##Source1_Text.set("Original Text")
    ##My_Service_ListTEST = Service.get()
    Source1 = Button(Standard_window, text=column2)
    Source1.grid(row=1, column=1)
    Source2 = Button(Standard_window, text=column3)
    Source2.grid(row=1, column=2)
    Source3 = Button(Standard_window, text='DCM')
    Source3.grid(row=1, column=3)

##Creating Function For Multicast IP Search
def Okay():
    hello = "Searching " + Group.get()
    myLabel = Label(root, text=hello)
    myLabel.grid(row=0, column=6)

##Creating Function For Source IP Search
def Okay2():
    hello2 = "Searching " + Source.get()
    myLabel2 = Label(root, text=hello2)
    myLabel2.grid(row=1, column=6)


##Creating Function For Service Search, when found it will return the signal flow
def Okay3():
    hello3 = "Searching " + Service.get()
    myLabel3 = Label(root, text=hello3)
    myLabel3.grid(row=2, column=6)
    if My_Service_List.__contains__(Service.get()):
        Searched_Service_Row_Location = excel_data_df[excel_data_df['ServiceName'] == Service.get()].index
        print(Searched_Service_Row_Location)
        return Standard_flow()
    else:
        None


##Creating Buttons
myButton_Group = Button(root, text='Group Multicast IP', command=Okay)
myButton_Source = Button(root, text='Source IP', command=Okay2)
myButton_Service = Button(root, text='Service Name', command=Okay3)

##Displaying Buttons
myButton_Group.grid(row=0, column=1)
myButton_Source.grid(row=1, column=1)
myButton_Service.grid(row=2, column=1)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please, provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example][1] .
  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I would be looking for something along the lines of

`Searched_Service_Row_Location = excel_data_df[excel_data_df['ServiceName'] == Service.get()].index
        print(Searched_Service_Row_Location)
        print(excel_data_df.loc(Searched_Service_Row_Location, colx=2)) `

Now that I have indexed the row I need, I need to print the columns of that row, but not all of them, I need to be specific.

Comment: I went down this path
`Searched_Service_Row_Location = excel_data_df[excel_data_df['ServiceName'] == Service.get()].index         print(Searched_Service_Row_Location)         print(excel_data_df.at(Searched_Service_Row_Location, "Device"))`

Comment: But get an error stating 

  File "C:/Users/206415779/Python/FINDIT/FINDIT START", line 79, in Okay3
    print(excel_data_df.at(Searched_Service_Row_Location, 'Device'))
TypeError: '_AtIndexer' object is not callable

Comment: So I somewhat got what I wanted

`Searched_Service_Row_Location = excel_data_df[excel_data_df['ServiceName'] == Service.get()].index
        print(Searched_Service_Row_Location)
        Searched_Service_Row_Location_Device = (excel_data_df.iloc[Searched_Service_Row_Location, 2])
        print(Searched_Service_Row_Location_Device)`

My only problem now is...This prints off several other things that I really do not want, I just want the value of that cell.

Comment: Found what was missing

`Searched_Service_Row_Location = excel_data_df[excel_data_df['ServiceName'] == Service.get()].index
        print(Searched_Service_Row_Location)
        Searched_Service_Row_Location_Device = (excel_data_df.iloc[Searched_Service_Row_Location]["DEVICE"])
        print(Searched_Service_Row_Location_Device.values)`

Was missing the .values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoping this will help someone later on, was able to grab what I needed. What was needed was the following 2 lines below. Using iloc I was able to specify what row/column I wanted to print, and I already had my row index stored under "Searched_Service_Row_Location", I simply added the below to print that row and column cell value. Probably not the cleanest, but at least for my problem this got me what I needed.

```
Searched_Service_Row_Location_Device = (excel_data_df.iloc[Searched_Service_Row_Location]["DEVICE"])
print(Searched_Service_Row_Location_Device.values)
```

```
from tkinter import *

import pandas as pd


database = pd.ExcelFile('C:/Code/CODETEST.xlsx').parse(sheet_name="Sheet1", skiprows=0, nrows=3)

excel_data_df = pd.read_excel('CODETEST.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1',)


WHAT = excel_data_df._values

print (WHAT)

print (excel_data_df)


##Creating a service list for all services listed under "Serivce name" Column
My_Service_List = (excel_data_df['ServiceName'].tolist())


My_Multicast_List = (excel_data_df['SRC DRAWING'].tolist())

column2 = excel_data_df.iloc[0, 3]
column3 = excel_data_df.iloc[:0, 4]


root = Tk()

##Creating Entries
Group = Entry(root, width=50)
Group.grid(row=0, column=5)
Source = Entry(root, width=50)
Source.grid(row=1, column=5)
Service = Entry(root, width=50)
Service.grid(row=2, column=5)

##Creating a global var to store row # of service searched
global Searched_Service_Row_Location
global Searched_Service_Row_Location_Device


##Creating Signal Flow Box
def Standard_flow():
    global Source1
    global My_Service_List
    global Test
    global column2
    global Searched_Service_Row_Location_Device
    Standard_window = Tk()
    ##Source1_Text = tk.StringVar()
    ##Source1_Text.set("Original Text")
    ##My_Service_ListTEST = Service.get()
    Source1 = Button(Standard_window, text=Searched_Service_Row_Location_Device)
    Source1.grid(row=1, column=1)
    Source2 = Button(Standard_window, text=column3)
    Source2.grid(row=1, column=2)
    Source3 = Button(Standard_window, text='DCM')
    Source3.grid(row=1, column=3)

##Creating Function For Multicast IP Search
def Okay():
    hello = "Searching " + Group.get()
    myLabel = Label(root, text=hello)
    myLabel.grid(row=0, column=6)

##Creating Function For Source IP Search
def Okay2():
    hello2 = "Searching " + Source.get()
    myLabel2 = Label(root, text=hello2)
    myLabel2.grid(row=1, column=6)


##Creating Function For Service Search, when found it will return the signal flow
def Okay3():
    global  Searched_Service_Row_Location_Device
    hello3 = "Searching " + Service.get()
    myLabel3 = Label(root, text=hello3)
    myLabel3.grid(row=2, column=6)
    if My_Service_List.__contains__(Service.get()):
        Searched_Service_Row_Location = excel_data_df[excel_data_df['ServiceName'] == Service.get()].index
        print(Searched_Service_Row_Location)
        Searched_Service_Row_Location_Device = (excel_data_df.iloc[Searched_Service_Row_Location]["DEVICE"])
        print(Searched_Service_Row_Location_Device.values)
        return Standard_flow()
    else:
        None


##Creating Buttons
myButton_Group = Button(root, text='Group Multicast IP', command=Okay)
myButton_Source = Button(root, text='Source IP', command=Okay2)
myButton_Service = Button(root, text='Service Name', command=Okay3)

##Displaying Buttons
myButton_Group.grid(row=0, column=1)
myButton_Source.grid(row=1, column=1)
myButton_Service.grid(row=2, column=1)


root.mainloop()
```